Computer Algebra System code flow-charts/pseudocode
Please let me know if this question should be on another StackExchange.
Anyway, here's the situation.
I've been a programmer for about 25 years now.
I've also got an amateur's interest in math (thanks, Pop!), and what I'm looking for is a way to adapt my programming skills to a more 'mathematical' way of thinking.
I figure it might make it easier for me to learn math, and might make me a better programmer as well.
One of the approaches that I think would be interesting is implementing some small aspect of a CAS in the language I'm most familiar with.
Ideally, I'd like to start out by implementing an algorithm that's already been diagrammed in a flowchart/decision tree, or spelled out in pseudocode, and then build off that to a more general description of a related algorithm that I would have to parse into separate steps myself.
The SageMath git doesn't seem to have anything so basic in it, and the GMP website is even more sparse.
Does anyone out there have any sources for such a starting point? And again, if this is in the wrong StackExchange, just let me know in a comment and I'll move it.

"Modern Computer Algebra" by Joachim von zur Gathen and Jurgen Gerhard could be of interest.

@RandyMarsh Ooh. That does look like a good option. Thanks!

@RandyMarsh can you post this as an answer? I'll accept it and close the question.

The textbook "Modern Computer Algebra" by Joachim von zur Gathen and Jurgen Gerhard discusses in depth the fundamentals of computer algebra, for example fast multiplication or factoring polynomials over finite fields.
One other great source that is independent of but also builds on the concepts of Modern Computer Algebra (and that is rather famous in computational mathematics) is "Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra" by Cox, Little and O'Shea.
